# How to resolve access to class not allowed

Tags: android, illegalaccessexception

I am calling a class from a `Jar file`.
But, as soon as that class is called, my application crashes and in LogCat I'm getting an Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed

at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)

at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
```

What could be the reason?
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I am just calling using Intent. sorry due to some security reasons I can not post my code . and class I am calling is inside Jar file

Comment: See the documentation of the API for this class. Maybe you are not allow and it throws the exception